# Puppeteer Does waitForSelector('selector') only work with strings and not page.$('selector')?

Tags: selector, puppeteer, wait

I'm using Puppeteer 3.0.2

I store my locators like this-> const ele = await page.$('.asd')

This doesn't seem to work-> waitForSelecttor(ele, { visible:true })

I don't want to have to use a string like this->

const ele = '.asd'

waitForSelecttor(ele, { visible:true })

I want to use one selector for everything, not a string and a-> const ele = await page.$('.asd')

Even if I have to make a function to do the same thing.

How can I do this?

Comment: If  `$` would return an element you wouldn't need to wait for it. and if you need to wait for it `$` would fail.

Comment: The automation is so fast that I need a wait for $ so it doesn't fail before the element is visible.

Comment: So if you have to wait for that `ele` you have to wait *before* calling `$`

Comment: I want to create a method that poles for a successful visibility of the element on the screen for lets say 10 seconds before it fails if the element is really not there.